# Should I use numeric error codes or semantic ones for my RESTful JSON API?

Tags: json, api, rest

I'm extending the error reporting for a RESTful JSON API.

Currently if there is a problem with a request, we return HTTP 400 Bad Request. We include some additional information in the response content which looks like this:

```
"resource_name": {
    "field_with_error": "error message"
}
```

I want to extend this to the following format:

```
"resource_name": {
    "field_with_error": {
        "message": "error message",
        "code": "error_code"
    }
}
```

My question pertains to the "code" field above.

Some APIs (such as [Facebook's Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/)) use a numeric error code. Others (such as [GitHub's API](https://developer.github.com/v3/#client-errors)) use a string.

Both approaches have upsides and downsides. A numeric error code is great because there is no need to translate the string to other languages for international users. A semantic code is nice because you don't have to maintain a list of numbers which you have already allocated.

A semantic code can be name spaced to avoid conflicts via a scheme like this:

```
<resource name>_<HTTP status code>_<short description>
```

E.g.:

```
invoices_400_malformed_email
```

Because of these two advantages I would very much like to use a semantic code. If internationalization ever becomes a requirement, we will just have to translate the resource name and short description as well, which does not seem like a huge problem.

Are there any problems with doing this, which I am not taking into account?

Comment: We ended up using the custom code but its important to watch out existing code and message being sent out ( just need to know information)